# Strange issue with php5 & httpd

Tags: php, mysql, httpd.conf

Issue 1:

I am getting the following message when starting httpd:

```
Starting httpd: [Thu Jan 12 18:05:40 2017] [warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
```

So I was opening the httpd.conf located at /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and couldn't find where php5 is getting loaded. Google ment that I should remove this part:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
```

Issue 2:

I am not able to use mysql correctly in php.
Google said that I should add a mysql extension to the php.ini.
Weirdly the php.ini is located at /opt/remi/php55/root/etc/php.ini.
Also at /opt/remi/ is a folder called php54 but I think that the folder is useless because I am using the version 5.6.29.
Also there's no module called 'mysql.so'.
Yes, I installed php and php-mysql.

I use CentOs 6.8.

Comment: Sounds like you've made a mess of your system. Vendor provided version is 5.3, you've got folders for 5.4 and 5.5, but you say you're using 5.6? I would start over again, and if you need an up-to-date version of PHP look at another distro. RHEL is conservative for a reason.

Comment: @mikken32: RHEL provides (optional) PHP 5.6 and 7.0. Is this really conservative ?
See https://www.redhat.com/en/about/press-releases/red-hat-software-collections-23-and-red-hat-developer-toolset-6-now-generally-available

Comment: @RemiCollet right I forgot about software collections. I use Scientific Linux, so I don't get those!

Comment: The packages in centos-scl repository should be usable on SL.

Comment: you just seem to be missing the mysql extension for php, which is not bundled together with the php package of your distro. In your distro try to install a packag named "php5-mysql" or similar. About the LoadModule warning it just says you used LoadModule for the same module twice, remove the repeated one and the message will go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed various versions of mod_php, when Apache only allows one.

So you got the expected warning "module php5_module is already loaded". You have to disabled unwanted versions (of uninstall them).

You are using Software Collections (from "remi-safe" repository) which are designed for parallel installation (so use path under /opt)

- If you use base version (php) you need php-mysql
- If you use SCL version 5.6 (php56-php), you need php56-php-mysqlnd

If you want a single version, probably simpler to not use the SCL, but the base packages available in "remi-php56" repository.

See the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions.

Comment: The exact meaning of the warning message is that a "LoadModule" directive with the same module has been used twice, difference versions is not assumed/reported in any way by httpd, just to complement this answer.